# unable to find schemalocation when building with maven

Tags: maven, xsd, wsdl, apache-axis, executionexception

I am trying to build an project which contains wsdl and xsd with maven.

when I am building it i am getting

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:axistools-maven-plugin:1.4:wsdl2java (default) on project (project_name)
Error generating Java code from WSDL. Error running Axis: C:\(project_name)\src\main\resource\xsd\schema.xsd (The system cannot find the file specified) -> [Help 1]
```

my schema.xsd present in src\main\resource\nms\xsd\schema.xsd

my schema.wsdl present in src\main\resource\nms\wsdl\schema.wsdl

in schema.wsdl schemaLocation is

```
<xsd:import namespace="nms" schemaLocation="../xsd/schema.xsd"/>
```

according to wsdl xsd is present in right location but axis2 tool searching it in different folder.
Provide me some help, Thank you.

maven wsdl2java configuration

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>



    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>axistools-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <configuration>
            <verbose>false</verbose>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/resources/</sourceDirectory>
            <wsdlFiles>
                <wsdlFile>schema.wsdl</wsdlFile>

            </wsdlFiles>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you add the configuration of wsdl2java?

Comment: Added maven axistool configuration which contains wsdl2java.

Comment: Try to change the directory to <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/</sourceDirectory>